# Convert a `TransformingRandomAccessList<T>` to just `List<T>`

Tags: java, android

After calling `Lists.transform`, we get a `TransformingRandomAccessList`. It is great except when trying to parcel it, we get an exception crash:

> Caused by: org.parceler.ParcelerRuntimeException: Unable to find generated Parcelable class for com.google.common.collect.Lists$TransformingRandomAccessList, verify that your class is configured properly and that the Parcelable class com.google.common.collect.Lists$TransformingRandomAccessList$$Parcelable is generated by Parceler.

```
List<Foo> items = List.transform(...);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("MyItemsKey", Parcels.wrap(items));
```

Any quick and easy to to convert `items` to a normal list. Or is there a better way to put this into a `Bundle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use this:

```
ImmutableList.copyOf(items);
```

Another alternative is using the one from the java libs

```
new ArrayList<Foo>(items);
```